# The captured images does not save to the storage on some android devices

Tags: java, android

I am building an android application using java.
https://github.com/skydragon1115/Android_Camera

But the image does not save to the storage on the below devices.

Galaxy Feel2 SC-02L       OS：Android 10

dtab Compact d-01J        OS：Android 7.0

This function is working on the others.

```
 try {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String fileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/Camera/");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1);
            } else {
                File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                File file = new File(directory, "Camera/" + fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            try (OutputStream output = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)) {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Comment: You should never catch and ignore an exception like you're doing.  At least log the exception.  It's probably telling you exactly what the problem is!

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason.

```
        try {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String fileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "captured image");

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                final String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + File.separator + "Camera" + File.separator;
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 0);
            } else {
                File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                File file = new File(directory, "Camera/" + fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            try (OutputStream output = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)) {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```